how to create accurate c++ timers loops for RTSP captures
So I'm trying to capture a stream and write it to 30 seconds chunks. I don't know what the cameras fps will be so need to factor in that I want to only capture 15 fps.
my problem is that the following results in 28 seconds chunks instead of 30. how can I get the timing right?
Not complete new to c++ but pretty rusty and never done anything like this before (usually simple i/o or in the context of entry level game dev)
firgure either math is off or I'm doing something that causes a delay in processing or I've just been looking at it too long and missing something obvious (likely)
what I have tried so far:
int frame_count = 0;
double frame_duration = 1.0 / currentCameraConfig.fps;
auto start_time = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();

while (true) {
    cv::Mat frame;

    if (!cap.read(frame)) {
        break;
    }

    frame_count++;

    auto now = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    auto elapsed_time = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::seconds>(now - start_time).count();

    if (elapsed_time < 30) {
        video_output.write(frame);
        std::cout << "[INFO]: elapsed time " << elapsed_time << std::endl;
        std::cout << "[INFO]: Saving video frame " << frame_count << " at " << currentCameraConfig.fps << " fps....cam " << std::endl;
    }

    if (cv::waitKey(1) == 'q' || elapsed_time >= 30) {
        std::cout << "\n [INFO]: Stopping recording..." << std::endl;
        break;
    }

    auto frame_end_time = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    auto frame_elapsed = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(frame_end_time - now).count();

    int sleep_time = static_cast<int>((frame_duration * 1000) - frame_elapsed);
    if (sleep_time > 0) {
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(sleep_time));
    }
}

cap.release();
video_output.release();
std::cout << "Video saved successfully.!" << std::endl;


Look into using sleep_until in place of sleep_for.  This eliminates the need for you to compute the amount of time to sleep for.  And it will average out errors in the duration of sleep to zero.  Just choose the set of time points you want to sleep until before hand:  tp, tp + 1 frame, tp + 2 frames, etc.  And then sleep until those time points.

thank you for the suggestion. this helped me on my way: keeping the end time calculation out of the while loop, using ms instead of seconds and using sleep_until got it there.

The elapsed time in your currently code might lead to a loss of precision.
auto elapsed_time = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::seconds>(now - start_time).count();

if (elapsed_time < 30) {
    video_output.write(frame);
    std::cout << "[INFO]: elapsed time " << elapsed_time << std::endl;
    std::cout << "[INFO]: Saving video frame " << frame_count << " at " << currentCameraConfig.fps << " fps....cam " << std::endl;
}

Try to keep the elapsed time in  milliseconds to maintain precision.
auto elapsed_time_ms = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(now - start_time).count();

if (elapsed_time_ms < 30000) { // 30000 ms for 30 seconds
    video_output.write(frame);
    std::cout << "[INFO]: elapsed time " << elapsed_time_ms / 1000.0 << " seconds" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "[INFO]: Saving video frame " << frame_count << " at " << currentCameraConfig.fps << " fps....cam " << std::endl;
}

One more implicit concern... If currentCameraConfig.fps is not set correctly or if the camera captures frames at a different rate, this also can lead to mismatches in timing.

thanks for your input, realy the answer came from the first comment about swapping out sleep_for to sleep_until, this remove the need to calcuate elapsed time and instead just compare timestamps at the end of each iteration.  the sleep_time variable in the loop provides a one size fits all offset for cameras operating at different frame rates. The big issue left is in the last few lines where the CPU spikes when releasing the file , kinda semi solved by splitting the thread (but thats not an ideal solution).
